# Where are all those SQL Server sessions from?

Tags: sql-server, session, ssms

After launching SSMS (2008 R2) on my dev machine, which I launch with

```
"D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe" -nosplash -S localhost -d testdata
```

without doing anything,
in Activity Monitor I observe some sessions  (TestData is my default database)

[image]

Details of session 51:

```
select @@spid;
select SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel');
```

Details of session 52:

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(52)
```

Details of session 53:

```
SELECT
CAST(serverproperty(N'Servername') AS sysname) AS [Name],
'Server[@Name=' + quotename(CAST(
        serverproperty(N'Servername')
       AS sysname),'''') + ']' + '/JobServer' AS [Urn]
ORDER BY
[Name] ASC
```

Details of session 54:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @previous_collection_time datetime;
DECLARE @previous_request_count bigint;
DECLARE @current_collection_time datetime;
DECLARE @current_request_count bigint;
DECLARE @batch_requests_per_sec bigint;
DECLARE @interval_sec bigint;

-- Get the previous snapshot's time and batch request count
SELECT TOP 1 @previous_collection_time = collection_time, @previous_request_count = request_count 
FROM #am_request_count
ORDER BY collection_time DESC;

-- Get the current total time and batch request count
SET @current_collection_time = GETDATE();
SELECT @current_request_count = cntr_value 
FROM sys.sysperfinfo
WHERE counter_name = 'Batch Requests/sec' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;

SET @interval_sec = 
    -- Avoid divide-by-zero
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF (second, @previous_collection_time, @current_collection_time) = 0 THEN 1
        ELSE DATEDIFF (second, @previous_collection_time, @current_collection_time)
    END;

-- Calc the Batch Requests/sec rate for the just-completed time interval. 
SET @batch_requests_per_sec = (@current_request_count - @previous_request_count) / @interval_sec;

-- Save off current batch count
INSERT INTO #am_request_count (collection_time, request_count) 
VALUES (@current_collection_time, @current_request_count);

-- Return the batch requests/sec rate for the just-completed time interval. 
SELECT ISNULL (@batch_requests_per_sec, 0) AS batch_requests_per_sec;

-- Get rid of all but the most recent snapshot's data
DELETE FROM #am_request_count WHERE collection_time < @current_collection_time;
```

If to launch SSMS (connecting to nameless instance by Windows authentication) without options then I do not have session corresponding to above show as 52

What had I done to have all those sessions to be launched ?
I just do not remember all what I had been doing in my dev SQL Server 2008 R2 before...

**Update:**
I restored the same options to SSMS.exe (-nosplash -S localhost -d testdata), relaunched SSMS and now I have different details corresponding to session 51 details:

```
DECLARE @edition sysname; 
SET @edition = cast(SERVERPROPERTY(N'EDITION') as sysname); 
select case when @edition = N'SQL Azure' then 1 else 0 end as 'IsCloud'
```

Why did not I have it before?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those sessions are being used to pull data into the Activity Monitor.